# Whats the best way to import/export from a dataset in my application?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, import, export

I need to be able Import and Export data from my database in the app im developing. I have been having trouble finding the proper way to do this. I have to assume some of the people using this wont have Office installed so this process has to be able to work on its own.

Im using Visual Basic Express with SQL server 2008. Using LINQ to SQL with a local database.

I would like it to be a simple process for the users. Any sources or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get your data into a DataTable you could use SQLBulkCopy:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

SQLBulkCopy will upload your data from the DataTable into a SQL Server table.